# .Net Core Azure Function - Cannot bind

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, azure-functions

I am do I migration to .standard to .core, but I faced a problem:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'FunctionName'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind
>   parameter 'MyService' to type
>   IMyService. Make sure the parameter Type is supported
>   by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure
>   Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the
>   registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
>   builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

I am using a startup with autofac to resolve the dependency

```
 public sealed class Startup : IExtensionConfigProvider
    {
        private static IContainer container;

        public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyToCoreService>().InstancePerDependency();

            container = builder.Build();

            context.AddBindingRule<InjectAttribute>().BindToInput<dynamic>(inject => container.Resolve(inject.Type));
        }
    }
```

The NuGets are:

```
Autofac - 4.9.0
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage - 3.0.3
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.24
```

And the function:

```
public static async Task RunAsync([QueueTrigger(ASERVICETOGETANAME)]string blobInformation,
            [Inject(typeof(IMyService))]IMyService myService, 
            ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I try to downgrade the versions of nuget and .net core, but I didnt have any success, what more can I do resolve the dependency problem?

EDIT - The Startup class is not being called.

Comment: I have had a lot of issues doing this, create a new blank .net core functions app and copy your code over. At face value it seems tedious but it seems to end up quicker in the long run.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I did :/ , I am think it is related to the sdk.funtions version beacause the QueueTrigger was migrated to separated library

Comment: You do need to upgrade across the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution,

install the nugget `AzureFunctions.Autofac`

add `[DependencyInjectionConfig(typeof(Startup))]` in your function class.

on the startup class, make a construct passing a string :

```
public Startup(string functionName)
{
    Initialize(functionName);
}
```

on the Initialize:

```
 public void Initialize(string functionName)
 {
      DependencyInjection.Initialize(builder =>
      {
       // your injections
      }, functionName);

  }
```